# Could some identify this bird call? (from the hu - wolf totem)

Tags: species-identification, ornithology, bioacoustics

What species is making this sound?

You can hear the sound it makes at the end of the music video: [The HU - Wolf Totem](https://youtu.be/jM8dCGIm6yc?t=376)

Comment: Before the wolves howling yes?

Comment: yes. it starts at 06:16 at the video

Comment: You could try the forum at xeno-canto.org, if you don't know about that site yet.

Comment: Same bird from Spirited away. There's a part when they get off the train when you can hear it. If you figure that out, you'll find the bird

Answer (score 2):

I believe the bird sound belongs to a member of Gaviidae, specifically [*Gavia arctica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-throated_loon), which has a common name of the Arctic Loon or Black-throated Loon in North America and Black-throated Diver in Eurasia.

The first impression when I heard this was a loon/ diver. Since The HU are Mongolian throat singers, I assumed that they likely used a loon/ diver from Mongolia of which there is one breeding species of the five members of Gaviidae. You can listen to calls and sounds of Arctic Loons here: [Macaulay Library](https://macaulaylibrary.org/asset/279261871)

The Arctic Loon sounds much higher pitched than other species of Gaviidae, which is similar the call in the song at 6:16.

[image]

Comment: Yep, Loon was my thought too. Amazingly eerie calls.